# Measurability of "$\frac{f}{h}$"

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f,g,h$ are real valued measurable functions on a measure space $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$.

Let $\widetilde \Sigma$ be a sub-sigma algebra of $\Sigma$. i.e. $\widetilde \Sigma \subset \Sigma$

Assume $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ and and $f$ and $h$ are $\widetilde \Sigma$ measurable, and assume further that $h$ is non zero almost everywhere on $S$.

Then, can I conclude that $g$ is measurable with respect to $\widetilde \Sigma$?

My intuition is that since $h$ is non-zero almost everywhere, the "ratio" $\dfrac{f}{h}$ should be measurable with respect to the sub-sigma algbera, but I am not sure how to rigoursouly showing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example. $S$ is the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, $\Sigma$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $S$, and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure (area) on $(S,\Sigma)$. $\tilde\Sigma$ is the $\sigma$-algabra of subsets of $S$ of the form $B\times[0,1]$, where $B$ is a Borel subset of $[0,1]$. Lets take $f(x,y)=x^2$ and $h(x,y)=x$ for all $(x,y)\in S$. Both $f$ and $h$ are $\tilde\Sigma$ measurable. Finally, define $g(x,y)=x$ for $(x,y)\in(0,1]\times[0,1]$ but $g(0,y) =y$ for $y\in[0,1]$. Then $g$ is $\Sigma$ measurable but not $\tilde\Sigma$ measurable, $f=gh$ everywhere, and $\mu(\{(x,y):h(x,y)=0\})=0$.

Comment: I asked you the question about measruability as I am working on the Exercise 4.12 on pg 48 of the book "Probability with Martingales" by Williams. Following the hint, I want to show that $Y_0 \in mL$, which at first seems immediate since $Y_0 = \frac{X_{n+1}}{Y_1 Y_2 Y_{n+1}}$ and $X_{n+1}$ and each $Y_i$ is measurable with respect to $L$, but without knowing $Y_i$ cannot be zero, I cannot really conclude that $Y_0$ is measurable with respect to $L$. Can I?

Comment: You raise a good point. Because each $Y_n$ is $\pm1$ a.s., we have $Y_0=X_nY_1Y_2\cdots Y_n$, a.s., for each $n\ge 1$. Thus $Y_0$ is "almost" $\mathcal L$ measurable.  If you assume that the $Y_n$ sequence has been constructed on the space $\Omega$ of sequences of $1$s and $-1$s, then $Y_n(\omega)=\pm 1$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, and the equality $Y_0=X_nY_1Y_2\cdots Y_n$ holds identically on $\Omega$, and $Y_0$ is $\mathcal L$ measurable.

Comment: Thank you for following up on my question. Just to double check that I understand, we indeed have to remove the set $\{w \in \Omega : Y_n(w) = 0 \text{ for some n }\}$ from $\Omega$ to claim that  $Y_0$ is $L$- measurable. Or equivalently, we can "view" $Y_n$ as random variables defined on $\Omega$  - $T$, and this is not too "crazy"(srry for the language) since $T$ has measure 0 anyways?